# Evaluation of loop condition takes too long

Tags: matlab

In the following script,

```
syms x1 x2 x3;
f = -x1-x2-x3;
u = 1;
B = -log(20 - x1) - log(20 - x2) - log(25 - x3) - log(log(x1) - x2) - log(30 - x1 - x2) - log(30 - x1 - x3) - log(x1) - log(x2) - log(x3);
Theta = f + u * B;
% LS (x0, a, b, c)
xk = [5; 1.5; 5];
e = 0.1;
% Back Tracking (b, c, a)
b = 0.5;
c = 0.1;
a = 1;
% Hoising
D_Theta = gradient(Theta);
% LS Algorithm
while (norm(subs(D_Theta, [x1; x2; x3], xk)) >= e)
    Pk = - subs(D_Theta, [x1; x2; x3], xk);
    % Back Tracking Algorithm
    while (double(subs(Theta, [x1; x2; x3], xk + a * Pk)) > double(subs(Theta, [x1; x2; x3], xk) + c * a * Pk' * subs(D_Theta, [x1; x2; x3], xk)))
       a = a * b;
       double(a)
    end
    xk = xk + a * Pk;
    double(xk)
end
```

the time to evaluate the condition of the inner loop (line 19) is surprisingly **so long** (i.e. it takes hours!).
What is the reason and how can it be fixed?

Comment: symbolic math is slow. I assume you mean the time to evaluate multiple iterations of the inner loop

Comment: @AnderBiguri do you suggest any solution?

Comment: Can't you do this numerically?

Comment: @AnderBiguri The first 5 iterations are evaluated quickly, but the 6th, for example, takes 10min and so it keeps increasing.

Comment: Its `xk`, its symbolic, and it gets massive

Comment: @AnderBiguri I can, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not? Everything in the algorithm is numeric. If you want to do symbolic, then its slow. Thats how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have any specific need of keeping your numeric variables symbolic, just make them numeric:

change your the lines to  `xk=double(xk);` and the iterations wont increase in time consumption, as the biggest problem of your code is that the number in `xk` gets more and more terms in each iteration.

With this change, the whole code takes 9.7s in my PC